# App Script for Copying Files and then Sharing those files to specific email addresses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've written this so far, which successfully copies the files into their destination:

```
      function createCopy()
{
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of copied file"); // ID of file you are copying
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Sheet with names and Emails").getSheetByName("Sheet"); //Full url of the file and then the name of the sheet you are copying
  let range = sheet.getRange("Range of filenames"); // Range where the file names are
  let values = range.getValues();
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Destination Folder"); // ID of hte folder where you want the copies to be made.
  for(let i=0; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    file.makeCopy(values[i].toString(), folder);
  }
}
```

I'm now trying to share those files with individual emails, this is what I have tried so far

```
  function createCopy()
{
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of file to copy"); 
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Sheet with names and emails').getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getRange('D2:D5'); 
  let email = sheet.getRange('C2:C5')
  let values = range.getValues();
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Destination Folder");

  for(let i=0; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    file.makeCopy(values[i].toString(), folder).addEditor(email);
    
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

> Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Range) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.addEditor.

Comment: addEditor(email), addEditors(emails) Reference addEditors(emailAddresses: string[]): DriveApp.File
An array of email addresses of the users to add. But you trying to add a spreadsheet range to the editor. Not email. You can make a log to see what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, just so I understand, I am currently asking it to add every email address in the array, rather than 1 address per copy made? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function createCopy() {
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of file to copy");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Sheet with names and emails').getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getRange('D2:D5');
  let email = sheet.getRange('C2:C5').getValues().flat();
  let values = range.getValues();
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Destination Folder");
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(values[i]);
    file.makeCopy(values[i].toString(), folder).addEditor(email);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now I get this error "The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.addEditor.createCopy", and it only makes one copy of the document.

Comment: What is Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values))

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I need to know what the first parameter of the makeCopy is. Use logger.log to get the debug information for me or figure it out for yourself

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will try to work out how to do that.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I cannot get logger to work, I am very new to this. I think the first parameter is just an email address.

Comment: I put it into the code for you please run it and tell me what you get

Comment: .addEditor(email)  to .addEditors(email).    let email = sheet.getRange('C2:C5').getValues().flat();  return [ ], addEditor will not accept [],  addEditors(email) will.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thank you for your help! I input the code and got this error: Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.addEditor.
createCopy @ Code.gs:10

Comment: Ah, @liquidkat, that makes sense, but when I changed it to add.Editors(email) it sends a copy to every email in the list, but I just want it to send to the associated email in the same row.

Comment: @IggyHannon then you should use addEditor(email[i])

Comment: @liquidkat Thank you so much! It seems so simple now.